# TextBox text format in C#

Tags: c#

I want something like this 01 or 02 or 03 but not 00 in my textbox i.e. both the digits allowed in the textbox should not be 0.

Again clearly I don't want first 0 followed by second 0 in textbox. 
So do anyone has got idea?

Comment: can you just do a simple Regex?

Comment: so you could write a regex and then you need to create a validation set of events for the text box.  Or you could catch the text entry to block it.  Or if you can write a good mask, then you could use MaskedTextBox to make your UI work nicely.

Answer (score 6):

In your format string (when you call ToString) you can use a `;` character to define a "zero" format like this:

```
myTextBox.Text = myNumber.ToString("00;;Something");
```

[MSDN Custom Numeric Formatting: Semicolon Separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator)

Answer (score 1):

if the content of your text box value is integer, cause it's not clear form your quesiton, can use something like this:

```
public string GetFormattedString(int iValue) {
    if(iValue!=0)
      return iValue.ToString("00");

    return string.Empty;
}
```

This returns '01', for example, and for 0 returns "".

If it's not ok, please explain better what you actually need.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a MaskedTextBox as well?

Comment: ya I want to use maskedtextbox to display something like this 2068/12/23 which is a nepali date but again i wanna be able to increment numbers before '/' where seected when pressing arrow key up and decrease the same while pressing arrow key down.

Comment: You might want to look at some custom controls, something like the telerik windows forms might have a box that does what you want.  That said, shouldn't a "DateTimePicker" control work provided the user is in nepalese culture?

Comment: Dear Spence,I am really sorry to say that I am not getting your points, So would you please explain in a bit details.

Answer (score 1):

Don´t know if you mean it so. But you can use the TextChanged Event.

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (textBox1.Text == "00")
     {
        textBox1.Text = "";
     }
  }
```

If the Text in the Textbox changed, you can check if the Text is "00".
Then you can handle it, in my example the Textbox is empty again.

Hope that I understand you right and could help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate input text from textbox control you can use the Regex
in your case it will be like this

```
        string strRegex = @"^\d[1-9]$";
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
        string strTargetString = @"03"; // put here value from text box
        if (myRegex.IsMatch(strTargetString))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect input");
        }
```